# Number of solutions for a particular subset sum

Tags: dynamic, recursion

Let's say we have a set : {1, 2, ..., n}. 
How many subsets of order R exist S = {a_i1, a_i2, ...a_iR} that sum up to a certain number S?. What is the recursion for this problem?

Comment: Have you written something that doesn't work; if so, what?  Can you show ANY work toward a solution?

Comment: I've tried to find a direct formula starting from the number of ways of writing a number S as a sum of n integers, then i've tried to add the domain restriction, but this didn't take me anywhere. 
My second approach was to find a recursion. It's clearly that i can view the sum of R numbers as adding one number to the sum of R - 1 numbers. So it's a dynamic problem. The last number i would add is from the set {1, 2, .., n}, so i should use T_(R - 1, S), T_(R - 1, S - 1), ..., T_(R - 1, S - n).(T_(R, S) number of ways to add R numbers from 1...n to sum up to S), but i can't find the coefficients

Answer (score 0):

Just define method to solve original problem. Parameters it receives are:

- max number to use (n),
- subset size (R),
- subset sum (S),

and returns number of combinations.

To implement this method, first we have to check is it possible to make this request. It is not possible to fulfill task if:

- subset size is larger than number of possible elements (R > n)
- maximal possible sum is smaller than S. `n + (n-1) + ... + (n-R+1) < S => R*((n-R) + (R+1)/2) < S`

After that it is enough to try all possibilities for larger element that will go in subset. In python style it should be implemented like:

```
def combinations(n, R, S):
  if R > n or R*((n-R) + (R+1)/2) < S:
    return 0
  c = 0
  for i in xrange(R, n+1):  # try i as maximal element in subset. It can go from R to n
    # recursion n is i-1, since i is already used
    # recursion R is R-1, since we put i in a set
    # recursion S is S-i, since i is added to a set and we are looking for sum without it
    c += combinations(i-1, R-1, S-i)
  return c
```